# JPanel vs JFrame when animating

Tags: java, animation, jframe, jpanel

I recently did a program which moves an image along the window and forces it to change its direction when it hits the borders. The animation happened within a JPanel class which was then of course added to a JFrame class which contains the main() function. Now my question is why must it be done in this manner. Can't I simply have just the JFrame and use that both as my window and my animation class which moves the image? Is the JFrame incapable of representing animation on it's own. 
Regards.

Comment: A JFrame is simply a container. When you add components to a JFrame you add them to the content pane. Well, the content pane is simply a JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omar's answer is correct but I thought I might elaborate just a bit:
Though JFrame's **are** capable of hosting your animation, it is not a **typical** use of the JFrame.  JFrame's are typically the outermost visual container and host one or more other visual containers (such as JPanel).  Though there are exceptions, I would consider the JPanel the most flexible and common way to contain your animation (or other GUI 'controls') to leave you flexibility for adding visual features later.

But as Omar points out, either JFrame or JPanel can be used as they are both considered "containers" in Swing.  Tying back to my last comment, using a JPanel is a bit more flexible.  For instance, you might later want to incorporate your animation into an Applet/JApplet which you might find confusing and/or difficult if you used a JFrame.

I tried to just comment on Omar's answer but I am a new user and it won't let me add comments yet.  Therefore, upvotes are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just better to use JPanel as you may want multiple Panels in one frame each with different animations.

Yes, you could do it with JFrame as well.